# Use a custom xml namespace prefix in type attribute

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces, xsd-validation, prefix, xml-validation

I want to introduce a new namespace and prefix "extending" `hod:string` from `xsd:string`.  Then in my schema I could define a string element:

```
<xsd:element name="Label" type="hod:string"/>
```

This way I can change the maxLength of all elements of type `hod:string`, for example, to 80.  If that requirement changes later to 50, I could simply change `hod:string`'s definition in a single place.  This is what I'm trying--my IDE doesn't like line 15 ("cannot resolve symbol hod:string"):

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns:hod="http://hod.com/2019/XMLSchema/hod"
       attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xsd:simpleType name="hod:string">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:maxLength value="80"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>

  <xsd:complexType name="Object">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Label" type="hod:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="MateriaID" type="GUID"/>
  ...
```

I changed all '`hod:string`' with '`mystring`' to verify I was defining things right and it seems happy, but I *want* to use the prefix if possible.  (also tried to change this: `attributeFormDefault="qualified"` but it didn't seem to make a difference)

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#declare-datatype shows that the `name` attribute of the `simpleType` element needs to be an `NCName` so `name="hod:string"` is not allowed. If you want to declare a type in a particular namespace set up a schema with the namespace as the `targetNamespace` and `xs:import` the schema.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I tried what you said and the IDE is happy, but when I run it this exception is thrown: System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException : Type 'http://hod.com/2019/XMLSchema/hod:string' is not declared.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I got it working. I had figured the import would cause `XDocument.Load` to automatically load the .xsd file referenced in `<xsd:import>`.  That is apparently not the case; I looked for an option to auto-load it but didn't find one.  Calling `XmlSchemaSet::add` for the new file fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple types get their namespace from the `targetNamespace` attribute on the `xs:schema` element. Since your `xs:schema` element has no `targetNamespace` your current elements/types, including your custom string type, have no namespace.

If you want to keep your current elements in no namespace and only have your string type be namespaced, you need to define the type in a new schema that has a different `targetNamepsace`, and import that into this schema. For example:

**hodtypes.xsd**

```
<xsd:schema
       xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns:hod="http://hod.com/2019/XMLSchema/hod"
       targetNamespace="http://hod.com/2019/XMLSchema/hod">

  <xsd:simpleType name="string">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:maxLength value="80"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>

</xsd:schema>
```

**main.xsd**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns:hod="http://hod.com/2019/XMLSchema/hod"
       attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xsd:import namespace="http://hod.com/2019/XMLSchema/hod" schemaLocation="hodtypes.xsd" />

  <xsd:complexType name="Object">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Label" type="hod:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="MateriaID" type="GUID"/>
      ...
```

Comment: thank you, that worked.  I just had to add the new schema to the XmlSchemaSet before validating.